# Sending emojis using mailR - iPhone mail preview renders question marks (iOS 12)

Tags: ios, r, unicode, utf-8

I am trying to send emojis using the mailR package.
What I was able to do so far is using utf-8 code: =?utf-8?Q?=F0=9F=98=98?= to send emojis via 
the subject argument.
I also can send Unicode via body argument like this ☀
but then the preview in apple mail (iOS and macOS) is just showing a question mark. When I view the complete mail, then this code is correctly rendered.

Some (old) unicode like this "&#9787" symbol: "☻" 
is rendered correct in the mail preview (also called preheader)
(also this unicode is rendered correct)

Also here  at stack overflow this seems to render fine
😘 : &#x1f618

My suggestion is that the iOS mail preview is not using html.
But unfortunately when using simply the mail app then symbols render correct.
I think that mailR induces encoding errors.

```
mailR::send.mail(from = "bla@gmail.com",
             to = c("bla@gmx.de"),
             subject = paste0("sweet mailR (",Sys.time(),") =?utf-8?Q?=F0=9F=98=98?="),
             body = paste0("<html><head><meta http-equiv='Content-Type'  content='text/html charset=UTF-8' /></head><font color='red'>Hello world",utf8::as_utf8("") ,"&#x1f618;  &#127828; &hearts; &#x263A; &#9787; &#x2600; &#9728; </font><p>&#128536;</p></html>"),
             smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com", port = 465, user.name = "bla@gmail.com", passwd = "pass", ssl = TRUE),
             authenticate = TRUE,
             send = T,
             inline= T,
             html = T,
             encoding = "utf-8")
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

&#x1f618 is the string of HTML entities isn't it? Have you tried literal UTF-8?
i.e. \xF0\x9F\x98\x98

Comment: this renders into ðð , do I need any escape characters ?

Comment: Thanks @Dare,

the solution was to use

\uF0\u9F\u98\u98

instead. 

Great, kind wishes...